# Get the next highest date value after excluding values from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `myDate variable` with the value `18-Nov-2013`.Each day its value is being changed.Tommorow this `myDate variable` will have the value `19-Nov-2013`.I have a list of values that i have `mapped` into a single `array` named `exclude` which contains some dates that are to be `excluded` ,now it has values `["20-Nov-2013",21-Nov-2013", "23-Nov-2010"]`  .How could i filter my value from the list of values from the `exclude array`.I need the `next highest value` from the array.So here i need the value `22-Nov-2013` after tommorrows date.Could someone help me with this.

Comment: You could loop trough your array of dates and see which one has the smallest difference with the current date.

Comment: Ok, so.. you need the highest value from `myDate` based on what? Any date *after tomorrow* but before the first date on `excluded` array?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I need the next date for my `myDate variable` that is not listed in the `excludes array`

Comment: @Outlooker is exclueds array sorted ?

Comment: @MD. Sahib Bin Mahboob :no.the array is not sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var excluded = ["30-Nov-2013","01-Dec-2013","02-Dec-2013"];
var myDate = "29-Nov-2013";
var month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var current = new Date(myDate);
while(true){
    current = new Date((current.getDate()+1<10? "0"+(current.getDate()+1):(current.getDate()+1))+ "-" + month[current.getMonth()] + "-" + current.getFullYear());
    var checkDate = (current.getDate()<10? "0"+(current.getDate()):(current.getDate()))+ "-" + month[current.getMonth()] + "-" + current.getFullYear();//this is necessary for when the +1 on day of month passes the month barrier
    if(-1 == excluded.indexOf(checkDate))
        break;

}
alert(checkDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach, or if is the best algorithm, but you may try this:

```
var myDate = ["17-Nov-2013", "18-Nov-2013"];
var excluded = ["20-Nov-2013", "21-Nov-2013", "23-Nov-2013"];
var months = {"Nov": 10}; // Add others months "Jan": 1, "Fev": 2 etc...

function findExcluded(date) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < excluded.length; i++)
    {
        if (excluded[i] === date)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function nextDate() 
{
    var last = myDate[(myDate.length - 1)];
    var s = last.split("-");
    var d = new Date(s[2], months[s[1]], s[0]);
    var next = new Date(d); 

    var chkDate = "";
    do 
    {
        next.setDate(next.getDate() + 1);
        chkDate = next.getDate() + "-" + findMonth(next.getMonth()) + "-" + next.getFullYear();
    } while(findExcluded(chkDate));

    return chkDate;
}

function findMonth(m) 
{
    var i = 10; // When you fill all months on 'months' array, this variable should start at '0' in order to loop to works.

    for (var month in months)
    {
        if (i == m)
        {
            return month;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

var nd = nextDate();
alert(nd);
```

See it woring [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99A2b/).

Answer (score 0):

No code ? Well here will be my method:

```
1.Get next date for mydate. Say that is var nextDate.
2.Check whether that date exist in the array.
3.If exists add one more day to nextDate. Again check in the array. 
4.Do it until you get a date which is not present in your exclude array
```

For checking whether it exists in the array you can use `arrValues.indexOf(nextDateInProperFormat) > -1`